aws-amplify requires us to use @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
I wanted to move away from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage and replace it with react-native-mmkv. But the issue is aws-amplify installation mentions @react-native-async-storage/async-storage as compulsory installation. Would have been better if we could use the storage of our choice. I do not think there is any way for that is it?
